# Leaving company during company event

Tags: new-job, united-states, negotiation, notice-period, events

I'm interviewing with a few companies right now. (I'm a junior software developer at a tech startup.) If things work out well, I'll have one or two offers within the next 2 weeks. (I wasn't actively looking but these two roles came my way - so I didn't get to choose the timing here. I am interested in switching companies, though).

The problem is that I'm scheduled to attend a major, week-long company event happening in 2 weeks. Based on how the process is trending with these other interviews, I'm pretty concerned that I'll have to give my 2-weeks notice either during the event (my boss will be there) or in the week right before or after the event.

In any of those situations, it would likely be extremely uncomfortable since this event is viewed as a way of building up the team, solidifying coworker relationships, and overall investing in the culture for the sake of improving moral & ultimately keeping people at the company. The event costs the company a lot of money.

I don't have any reasonable way to avoid attending this event, especially not so last minute. (That would also be counter-productive if I end up staying).

I also want to a break before starting a new job - which means if I negotiate a later start date, I'd have to ask for nearly a month and a half befor starting (waiting 1-2 weeks before handing in notice, 2 weeks notice, and then 2 weeks break).

**From an outside perspective, how bad is it to give notice before, during, or right after an event like this?**

**How is it considered acceptable ask for a start date that's in 1.5 - 2 months?**

**Are there other potential options to avoid or pre-empt this situation?**

Comment: *If things work out well*. There's no guarantee you will have a job offer. Until you have that contract for you to sign in your hands (ie references are done), it should be business as usual. I've had to resign the next working day after going on a week long training course in the past - I felt a bit bad, but if it hadn't worked out, I would have been at a disadvantage in the current job not to have gone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There will never be a right moment to resign. No company is ever happy to see someone leave. (Well, unless you're very bad at your job)

Once/if you have a signed offer, it's definitely better to resign before the team building event. But don't preemptively quit. Quitting right after the event might be awkward, but do it politely and professionally and you shouldn't burn bridges too much.

Asking for a start date 1 month away is typical in North America. 2 months, depending on the field, might be stretching it, but there's really no problem asking. Worse case they say no. Personally, I'd ask during the interview about the starting date timeframe. It makes you look serious, organised and actually interested.
Quite often, offers come with start date, so it's harder to change it afterwards, but possible.

Comment: when you say to resign before the team event, do you mean to hand in notice before the event & then still attend?

Comment: +1. *During* the event, when everyone's attention needs to be focussed on it, is by far the worst of the three options.

Comment: @giraffe36 unless you are uninvited afterwards, just attend. Events like this are part investment and part reward for rendered services so it is up to your boss to decide which way the coin falls.

Answer (score 9):

Resigning during the event is not a good option. Not only is your boss likely busy with other things, but in many cases there will be some formalities involved, if only writing a letter to HR.

Do notice that a "2 weeks notice" is a minimum notice period. If you plan to leave 2 weeks after the company event, you can tell HR/your boss a week before the event that you intent to leave 3 weeks later. Not many bosses will say "couldn't you have waited another week to tell me?".

Answer (score 1):

Resign before the team building event (this way it would show that you are firm on your decision) and attend the event gracefully. Resigning after the event will just buy you time for the inevitable.

Negotiating a later start date depends how early the company wants to fill the position, the workload on the team and other factors.